# How to read a .md file marked as octet-stream

Tags: macos, binary, debian, markdown, octet-stream

Days ago I've written in vim on macOS 14.4 a markdown file ending with .md extension, as I did many times before with other files having similar purpose & structure.
Yesterday I tried to open the same file in vim on a server running Debian 12.5 and couldn't get the original file content.
When trying analyzing the file with:
`file -i $myfile.md`
I get:
`myfile.md: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

I don't know what happened but I suppose the file got corrupted while transferring it from my workstation to that server.
Reading articles online, it seems as any of my systems is being capable of recognizing what kind
of file it is, even though it has .md extension.\

I tried some of the advices I've found on the web, but I hadn't find any solution that would really fit to my problem, so I hope, if it could get solved, that it could help anyone else.

The only thing I've noticed is that if I write a new file on macOS, it has now the following charset:
`new.md: text/plain; charset=us-ascii # file -I on mac`
While markdown files written days ago on the same macOS and then transferred to the Debian server:
`old.md: text/plain; charset=utf-8 # file -i on debian`
Is there any way I could get my content back, using any OS?

Thank you in advance, have a nice day

Comment: Sounds like your file is corrupted. Restore it from your workstation.

Comment: the `application/octect-stream` is a fallback mimetype for anything that is not recognizable. its impossible to tell whether the text content of the original file can be restored from that binary data without having access to the binary data.

Comment: also, this doesn't seems to be a programming question, so you probably should have asked on [su] anyhow (but given the nature of the question, i doubt that you will get any reasonable answer)